# 3d in iOS (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, 3d

I am trying to do an iPad application which shows a 3d view of the kitchen and user can select parts of kitchen like, floor, wall, doors etc and customize. The kitchen view should be generated in a 3d view.

A native application is recommended for this or can I use any java script libraries like three.js or unity 3d?

If it can be developed in iPad native, is there any frameworks available?

This is what I am trying to create in iPad - https://virtualkitchenshowroom.homedepot.com/VS_EN_CA/UI/Pages/VPUI.htm?SkipIntro=Yes&PresetRoom=b0560f941f464282abf3b15776aa5815

Can somebody tell me it is possible or not?

Comment: Questions asking for suggestions for outside libraries or frameworks are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you question is full of small errors...

I will try to correct them as I answer them...

"Is native the recommended tool for this?" No, A tool like Unity3d would be far easier to work with, unless you want to learn `OpenGL` or `Metal`, both of which are not easy and hard to port across platforms.

"If it can be developed in iPad native, is there any frameworks available?" If you are set on native, Metal and OpenGL. But I suggest Using Unity 3d. Additionally, Unity 3d is not Javascript, it is C#, the UnityScript version of Unity3d is weaker and should not be used.

"Can somebody tell me it is possible or not?" Yes, this is a relatively easy project.